# Show a view of all nodes not being referenced by other nodes

Tags: views

In order to show a view with all nodes of type A not being referenced by other nodes of type B:

1. I created a view that contains the relation 'is referencing node'
2. I added the title field
3. I added a fielter: the NID field using the 'is referencing node' relation.
4. I turn on aggregation, and set this NID field to 'Count' with the value 0

This does not work. The filter works for all node count values exept zero. 
Apparently the views row is not displayed if the count is zero.

I have searched for solutions but have not found one yet.
Help is appreciated, thanks!